# Connecting localhost from within virtual WindowsXP (hosted on Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04

My host machine is on Ubuntu 10.04. I installed WindowsXP on VirtualBox.
In Ubuntu I'm running a server on `0.0.0.0:3000`, and I would like to access it from within WindowsXP. Already tried to set VM network type to Bridge -- I might be missing something, but it's not working -- can't access `127.0.0.1:3000` from Windows.

So, how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

from the VM 127.0.0.1 is the VM itself you need to find the address of the host.

The address you want for the host is the ip address used by the ethernet - so in your case 0.0.0.0 however that is not a real address so you need to find the address of the Ubuntu box via ifconfig.

If VM net interface is set to Bridged then the VM will find by DHCP an address using the same dhcp server the host does.

Comment: I wrote ifconfig as it id from the Windows VM you need the address and Windows uses ifconfig